# Populating select options Via ajax showing undefined -- Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

The options is populating with undefined and I'm not sure what i'm suppose to type to call the value correctly.  The problem seems to be with the javascript on the line:

products.append...

```
public function institutionProductsAction() {

    $input = Input::get('option');



    $products = ClientProduct::select('product_name', 'product_id') -> where('client_id', '=', $input) -> where('product_type_id', '=', '7')->get('product_name', 'product_id');

    $items = array();
    foreach($products as $product) {

        $items[$product->product_id] =   $product->product_name;

    }

    return $items;


}
```

Here is the javascript

```
$('.institution').change(function() {
    $.get("api/dropdown",
        { option: $(this).val() },
        function(data) {
            var products = $('.institution_products');
            products.empty();

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                products.append("<option value='" + element.product_id + "'>" + element.product_name + "</option>");
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
products.append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + element + "</option>");
```

you are returning this

```
$items[$product->product_id] =   $product->product_name;
```

the product id will be the index and the product name will be the value;

check the json that your server is returning. I bet will be something like

```
{
     "1": "name 1",
     "45": "name 2",
}
```